# Build python project as package without internet access

Tags: python, build, pip, package

I have a python project I want to package. I can package the project with `python -m build` just fine when connected to the internet.

When I disconnect and try the same command, I get an error about `pip` being unable to find the package `wheel`:

```
(my-venv) [me@my-host my-project]$ python -m build
* Creating venv isolated environment...
* Installing packages in isolated environment... (setuptools>=42, wheel)
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f5935bb4f10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /simple/wheel/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f5935b5a160>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /simple/wheel/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f5935b5a310>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /simple/wheel/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f5935b5a4c0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /simple/wheel/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f5935b5a670>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /simple/wheel/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement wheel
ERROR: No matching distribution found for wheel
```

This happens even if I install `setuptools` and `wheel` first.

How can I build my project without needing internet access at the time of building? Can I somehow make the isolated environment use my python cache?

Comment: I found the `--no-isolation` flag, but removing isolation seems kinda sketchy. Is this the recommended way?

Comment: Same problem here after re-creating my `~/miniconda3`. The `wheel` package was already there. Any resolution in the past year?

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same problem. Unfortunately it seems you can't modify the way `build` calls `pip` as seen in [`src/build/env.py:113`](https://github.com/pypa/build/blob/main/src/build/env.py#L113).

However you can configure `pip` via environment variables. What I did is setting [`PIP_CONFIG_FILE`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/configuration/).

In my particular case I only set the config file to avoid `pip` using an index:

```
[global]
no-index = true
```

You can then provide a directory with all the required dependencies as wheels and set it via the `PIP_FIND_LINKS` environment variable. Alternatively you can set the links (which can point to an URL or a local directory) or the index in the config file.