How to run python -m build behind proxy
I am trying to build a Python package via python -m build.
However, I am behind a corporate proxy. When I run the command it tries to download the prerequisites and fails with ConnectTimeoutError after several retries:
< WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001797563A510>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')'
Usually when using pip, the following command works for me:
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --proxy http://<username>:<password>@<IP>:<port> <package>
But I am not sure how to get things working with python -m build.

Set the http_proxy and https_proxy environment variables.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/76851348/3280538
